# Orange data mining - not loading excel columns as numeric

Tags: python, excel, orange

I am currently working on a project about satellites and visualizing particular data about satellites from each country. For the data I am using Microsoft Excel. When loading the data from it, everything is fine, except the fact that 4 of my columns (which contain only numeric data) are loaded only as meta strings. I checked each cell of the columns to see if they contain any particular strings..but I couldn't find anything. Below are the columns that are not taken as numeric. Any solutions ?

[image]

Comment: If *When loading the data from it* means loading data from your source into Excel, the problem may be that the decimal and group separators in the source are different from your Windows Regional Settings.

Comment: What do I need to do then ?

Comment: You will need to change the method you are using to get the data into Excel.  You have shown none of that.  This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I do not need to code anything... At least they didn't teach us how to code in Orange.

Comment: What part of **You will need to change the method you are using to get the data into Excel. You have shown none of that.** is not clear to you?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/oUlCc this is how I do it.

Comment: That looks like you're going from Excel to Orange. Your problem is in Excel.

Comment: Actually, what makes you think the data in your Excel sheet is text?  If the data in Excel is really numeric, but not being recognized as such by Orange, then your question might be better suited for the Stackoverflow **Orange** forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Excel to re-save your data as *comma-separated values* file (CSV). Ensure that numeric fields use period instead of comma as decimals separator (e.g. your *Inclination* and *Period* columns) as some programs might have trouble with that. Ensure there are no spaces in numeric values (your *Launch mass* column) and don't use thousands separators.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I've had the same issue and spent too much time figuring it out so I'm sharing what worked for me for the next person out here.
A simple fix: in your excel or csv file rename all numeric column headers so they start with a "C#". For example, my Var1 will now be C#Var1. Then load as excel or CSV file into Orange (fyi- excel format lets you reassigndaya type during loading; csv doesnt but you can do it with the "select columns" widget).

Please note that I watched the Orange video "how to load your data", and in their demo they create a subheader, marking columns as C for continuous and D for disreet data. However, that did not work for me. Re-saving the file as a tab text or a csv, changing comma to period separator, renaming with no space or special characters,  copying and pasting special "values only" to a new worksheet, checking that format is numeric throughout - did not fix the issue either.
But re-naming the actual headers with a #C or a #D did the trick (you can use an excel concatenate formula to do quickly).

~Maria